# Why do certain questions always come up as "Related" for totally awful C++-tagged questions?

Tags: discussion

By totally awful I mean those questions which are really hopeless, posted by people who don't have a clue about common programming terminology (much less C++) but are using C++  for their first programming project ever to produce a new game with fantastic AI allowing 1000x1000 spaceship combat ... etc. etc. etc. so please help me get started?

Now, a question like [The C++ Definitive Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1_) which always shows up as Related: That I get.

But what explains the frequency of the following as being related:

- [Image Processing: Algorithm Improvement for 'Coca Cola Can'
  Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/image-processing-algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-recognition?rq=1)
- [C++11 introduced a standardized memory model. What does it mean? And
  how is it going to affect C++
  programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g?rq=1)
- [What is the "-->" operator in
  C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c?rq=1)

I'm just curious about the "Related" algorithm. (Is it nothing more than that those are high-score questions?)

Comment: Those are the kind of questions I thought could never become popular today... until [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/1233251) happened.

Comment: I remember Jeff Atwood sighing about this.  The code removes all the noise words that are common in English, he found out that on some questions almost nothing was left to compare with.  So finding the same Q+A repeatedly with very little to work with is not surprising.  That this was not a good enough reason to reject such a question, well, imagine what the site would look like today if he did.  Hypothetically.